# is there a excel formula which will give me the highest year from column F, corresponding to every company code in column c

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need the highest year from column F  corresponding to each company code in column C of sheet usage [sheet usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVLsq.jpg) and to be output in column H(company code) and I(Year) of  [sheet IA+++0980](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7A9KO.jpg). The result needs to be something like the text in blue letters in column H and I of sheet IA+++++0980

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you could accomplish the desired output using `GROUPBY()`

[image]

---

```
=GROUPBY(SCAN(,D3:D29,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="",x,y))), --F3:F29,MAX,,0)
```

---

Or, Using `MAP()`

```
=LET(
     _Code, SCAN(,D3:D29,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="",x,y))),
     _Ucode, UNIQUE(_Code),
     HSTACK(_Ucode, MAP(_Ucode,LAMBDA(a, MAX(F3:F29*(a=_Code))))))
```

---

**Alternative Option One:**

Or, Using only one `LAMBDA()` helper, and not involving two `LAMBDA()`s

```
=LET(
     _Code, SCAN(,D3:D29,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="",x,y))),
     _Data, FILTER(HSTACK(_Code,F3:F29),F3:F29<>""),
     _Ucode, UNIQUE(_Code),
     HSTACK(_Ucode, XLOOKUP(_Ucode,TAKE(_Data,,1),TAKE(_Data,,-1),,,-1)))
```

---

**Alternative Option Two:**

```
=LET(
     _Code, SCAN(,D3:D29,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="",x,y))),
     _Data, FILTER(HSTACK(_Code,F3:F29),F3:F29<>""),
     _Ucode, UNIQUE(_Code),
     HSTACK(_Ucode, LOOKUP(_Ucode,_Data)))
```

---

**Note:** In both the alternative one & two it assumes that the years will be in sorted order.

---

Bit of explanations that may help:

- Using `LET()` function makes it easier to read and define variables for repeated ranges or functions.
- Since there are empty/blanks in the `Code` column hence we need to fill in order to make it comparable to get the max of year for each. There `SCAN()` function which helps in doing so. What it does, it applies a custom `LAMBDA()` function to each values in the given array and returns an array that contains each of the intermediate values.
- Using `UNIQUE()` function to get the unique codes.
- Using `FILTER()` function to remove the empty/blanks that are present in the `YEAR` column, hence gives us a compact merged data using `HSTACK()` combined with the array returned using `SCAN()` & `FILTER()`
- Next, as mentioned in notes, if the `YEAR` column is sorted for each code, then we can use either `XLOOKUP()` or `LOOKUP()` function to get the **Highest Year** for each code.

---

Including `G/L Account` & `Code`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H3</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _GL_Code, C3:D29,
     _F, LAMBDA(a,SCAN("",a,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="",x,y)))),
     _Data, FILTER(HSTACK(_F(TAKE(_GL_Code,,1)),_F(TAKE(_GL_Code,,-1)),F3:F29),F3:F29<>""),
     _Uniq, UNIQUE(TAKE(_Data,,2)),
     _MaxYears, XLOOKUP(TAKE(_Uniq,,1)&"|"&TAKE(_Uniq,,-1),INDEX(_Data,,1)&"|"&INDEX(_Data,,2),TAKE(_Data,,-1),,,-1),
     _Answer, HSTACK(_Uniq,_MaxYears),
     _Answer)
```

---

Using `GROUPBY()` function will be bit shorter ofcourse:

```
=LET(
     _GL_Code, C3:D29,
     _F, LAMBDA(a,SCAN("",a,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="",x,y)))),
     _Data, FILTER(HSTACK(_F(TAKE(_GL_Code,,1)),_F(TAKE(_GL_Code,,-1)),F3:F29),F3:F29<>""),
     GROUPBY(TAKE(_Data,,2),--TAKE(_Data,,-1),MAX,,0))
```

---

Comment: Note to that: GROUPBY() is a recent function that may not be available as of March 2024 on all Excel 365 installations.